# Nginx's fastcgi-php.conf snippet is missing

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm attempting to serve PHP with nginx, i've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04) successfuly before but on a new server for some reason I get the following error:

```
 nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

In fact, the whole `snippets` directory of the nginx installation is missing.

I've installed PHP with the following commands:
- `sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-cli  php7.0-cgi php-fpm php-mysql`
- `sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm`

I've installed the most up to date nginx that is available - and yet the directory and file is still not present.

How can this be remedied?

Bonus: What could have caused this?

Comment: did you install it on the new server?

Answer (score 44):

TLDR:

Final version is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    include fastcgi_params;                
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

---

i think it depends on the Nginx version you are using.

For Nate's answer, `nginx-full` will install 1.10.3 for you.

I'm using Nginx 1.12.2 on Ubuntu 16.04, with this version, it doesn't have `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` with it; and it also has a different PHP CGI setup.

You can either use Ulad Kasach's solution, or start to use the new way.

Here's an official doc for how to do it: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

BTW, in above post, you should also replace `fastcgi.conf` with `fastcgi_params`.

And add one more line which is in default orignially:

`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;`

These are all new changes with Nginx 1.12.2 :(

Final version is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    include fastcgi_params;                
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Comment: html was working, php was not, i looked everywhere, this one worked for me!

Comment: works on my Nginx 1.13.9 and php7.2-fpm:
`location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}`

Answer (score 12):

Ended up having to look at a previous, working, configurations file and replicating it manually. Simply made the `snippets` directory and added a `fastcgi-php.conf` file with the following content:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

You'll also need to replace the last line, `include fastcgi.conf;` with `include fastcgi_params;`.

I would have recommended to create the file `fastcgi.conf;` if it was not literally the same file with the additional line `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` in the case of `fastcgi.conf`

Answer (score 9):

Had me stumped for a moment too. You want to install the `nginx-full` package on ubuntu as opposed to just `nginx`. `nginx-full` contains the bits you were missing.

Comment: omg wasted an hour on this, thank you

Answer (score 7):

i am using

1. nginx/1.4.6
2. Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

and my site config looks like this

```
server {
    listen 3010;

    root /usr/share/nginx/docs;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;   

    server_name phpSetup;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and working nicely .
so i do recommend to update your 
config 
**include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;**
to

> **include fastcgi_params;**

so the location block is

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

> HOPE IT HELPS

read more on :
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

thanks,